# How to address the error EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, egl

I'm getting random error messages from selenium, even though none of them are related to the exact web driver commands I'm running (not that I know of).

This error isn't interrupting the program, it's just adding unwanted alerts (making my prints harder to read).

- Chrome version: 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Python version: 3.6.1
- ChromeDriver version: 75.0.3770.140

I've added the following code already but I'm still getting the error.

```
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
```

Error:

```
gl_surface_egl.cc(544) - EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

Answer (score 1):

This random error message...

```
gl_surface_egl.cc(544) - EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

...is coming from the `LogEGLDebugMessage()` method as there was an error with one of the [GL Switches](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/gl/gl_switches.cc?q=kGLImplementationEGLName&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=13)

This error is defined in [gl_surface_egl.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/ui/gl/gl_surface_egl.cc#674) as follows:

```
static void EGLAPIENTRY LogEGLDebugMessage(EGLenum error,
                       const char* command,
                       EGLint message_type,
                       EGLLabelKHR thread_label,
                       EGLLabelKHR object_label,
                       const char* message) {
  std::string formatted_message = std::string("EGL Driver message (") +
                  GetDebugMessageTypeString(message_type) +
                  ") " + command + ": " + message;
```

---

### Deep Dive

As per the documentation in [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) the argument [`--use-gl`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/gl/gl_switches.cc?q=kUseGL&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=97) selects which implementation of GL the GPU process should be used and the available options are:

- *desktop*: whatever desktop OpenGL the user has installed (Linux and Mac default).
- *egl*: whatever EGL / GLES2 the user has installed (Windows default - actually ANGLE).
- *swiftshader*: The SwiftShader software renderer.

This *DEBUG* message is not harmful and you can continue with your tests.

---

### Solution

If your usecase involves invoking `click()` or `send_keys()` method, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

- Invoking `click()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css"))).click()
  ```
- Invoking `send_keys()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_xpath"))).send_keys("Joseph Jones")
  ```

---

### Additional consideration

Possibly this error is caused by the app getting launched by `ES2-only` devices, even though the manifest requires `ES`3 capability. Updating `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE` from `EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT` to **`EGL_OPENGL_ES3_BIT`** will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The chrome://gpu page was a good lead.
My experience was: disabling hardware acceleration in the settings menu caused error messages to stop, but made a Babylon.js demo I was using as a benchmark run very slowly.
I went through and enabled all of the functionalities that were in red on chrome://gpu.
I now have a new error on start-up of Chrome that doesn't repeat:

```
[13837:13837:0505/004321.484642:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

With the occasional:

```
[13801:13801:0505/005551.603893:ERROR:CONSOLE(15)] "Uncaught TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt", source: chrome://gpu/vulkan_info.js (15)
```

The benchmark runs well now, though. Hopefully, this works for someone besides me. I'm on Linux with an AMD GPU driver, and judging by the "Problems Detected" portion, I suspect that is a contributing factor in my case. Well, good luck!