# DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using Brave Browser With Python Selenium and Chromedriver on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, brave-browser

I want to use Selenium (installed: ver 3.141.0.dist-info) on Python (3.8) which is installed on my Windows 7 64,
I Use Brave Browser Version 1.17.73 Chromium: 87.0.4280.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and

Chromedriver (chromedriver_win32-87.0.4280.20) for it,
when running the following Py file which I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-), new Brave browser opens up, but I get errors.

Any solution to make this works?
Appreciate your help.

when running this file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = 'C:/python/Python38/chromedriver.exe'
brave_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

get these errors:

```
c:/Users/mycomp/Desktop/Python/test/getwebdriver.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of 
chrome_options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)
[7132:3952:1127/003249.595:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(93)] Failed to decrypt: The parameter is incorrect. 
(0x57)
[7132:3952:1127/003249.596:ERROR:brave_sync_prefs.cc(114)] Decrypt sync seed failure

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51576/devtools/browser/a048c130-e608-4ec6-a388-ad67fc32d97a
[1127/003250.360:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003250.452:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003250.455:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003250.457:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003250.458:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003250.711:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003250.821:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003252.062:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.
[1127/003254.498:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: 
Bad attribute.

C:\Users\mycomp\Desktop\Python\test>[1127/003304.647:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message 
(Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

Edited:

I found a solution to this from another place, to add the following to the code, but I still get errors, fewer errors

```
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

I run it and got this error:

```
c:/Users/mycomp/Desktop/Python/test/getwebdriver.py:12: DeprecationWarning: 
use options instead of chrome_options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, 
chrome_options=option)
[6208:8532:1127/021046.062:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(93)] Failed to decrypt: The 
parameter is incorrect. (0x57)
[6208:8532:1127/021046.063:ERROR:brave_sync_prefs.cc(114)] Decrypt sync seed 
failure

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53262/devtools/browser/adb0a87d-298a- 
4b9c-ad00-132a607cb9bd
```

%20%20browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

The key `chrome_options` was **deprecated** sometime back. Instead you have to use **`options`** and your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = 'C:/python/Python38/chromedriver.exe'
brave_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium on Windows 10 system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310119/deprecationwarning-use-options-instead-of-chrome-options-error-using-chromedriv/63310208#63310208)
- [How to initiate Brave browser using Selenium and Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626853/how-to-initiate-brave-browser-using-selenium-and-python-on-windows/62627392#62627392)

Comment: thank you for the response, I tried your code, but it still throws error,  I guess same error:  some of them:` c:/Users/mycomp/Desktop/Python/test/getwebdriver2.py
[7088:9104:1127/022037.988:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(93)] Failed to decrypt: The parameter is incorrect. (0x57)
[7088:9104:1127/022037.990:ERROR:brave_sync_prefs.cc(114)] Decrypt sync seed failure

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53545/devtools/browser/288a869a-577c-400b-9ac7-7f318174d272
[1127/022048.029:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.`

Comment: @Dave99 `os_crypt_win.cc(93)] Failed to decrypt: The parameter is incorrect.` is a different error all together most possibly _Brave  Browser_ callback issue which needs further detailed investigation. I'm sure your initials error of `DeprecationWarning` is solved now.

Comment: I installed new version of Chrome, tried to use Selenium with the same version of webdriver, getting error on: `GL Driver message (Error)`  `1127/130527.830:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.`  maybe I should use Firefox, I use Brave because it is fast, Chrome in my machine works very slowly.

Comment: I was reading a post about this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090258/how-to-address-the-error-egl-driver-message-error-eglquerydeviceattribext-bad?rq=1), that if it involves invoking click() or send_keys()  use some code block, but I just load a web browser to test, does it involve any of these? to use any of the code blocks? I installed python on my windows machine, does this ES2-only devices, can have anything to do with it? I thought these ES2 devices are only devices like mobile.

Comment: @Dave99 I constructed that answer in the beginning of 2020 since then Chrome/ChromeDriver have got updated. No doubt Chrome/ChromeDriver combo currently fails on a couple of unharmful callbacks, but incase of _Brave_ it seems to be having a larger impact which needs deeper analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you are now seeing `WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'`, this is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

`chrome_options` has been removed. Also, the driver manager is now built-in to selenium, so you no longer need to use the separate `webdriver_manager`. The Selenium Team talked about that here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/selenium-manager-best-tool-from-you-can-forget-david-burns/

Use the `service` and `options` args for passing in settings:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

---

NOTE: Someone incorrectly closed [WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument chrome_options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76736724/7058266) as a duplicate and pointed to this page as having answers, but it's not the same question. This solution answers the question marked as a duplicate.