# Seleneium Python shows DeprecationWarnings with driver.find_element_by_xpath()

Tags: python, selenium, deprecation-warning, findelement, selenium-webdriver-python

Okay, so I am working on my laptop rn and I copy and pasted my code from my PC and suddenly it's not working. I have installed the same Selenium but now it is acting up, I am receiving DeprecationWarnings, driver.find_element_by_xpath isn't working etc.

```
def click():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options_)
    driver.get("http://www.discord.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

This is an example of what I have written which is no longer working, the `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` has a line through it! And when I rewrite this in another py file (in pycharm) it does not like me using driver, it comes up underlined in red.

Can somebody explain what on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
 DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated
```

...implies that the *`find_element_by_*`* commands are now associated with a [DeprecationWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875984/7429447) in the latest Selenium Python libraries.

---

This change is inline with the *Selenium 4 Release Candidate 1* [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L32) which mentions:

> Specify that the "find_element_by_* ..." warning is a deprecation warning (#9700)

---

### [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) compatible code

Instead of *`find_element_by_*`* you have to use *`find_element()`*. An example:

- Using *`xpath`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath")
  ```

> You need to add the following import:
>
> ```
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> ```

---

Additionally, you have to use **`options`** instead of `chrome_options` as `chrome_options` is deprecated now.

> You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:
>
> - [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium on Windows 10
>   system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63310208/7429447)
> - [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using Brave Browser With Python Selenium and Chromedriver on
>   Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030107/7429447)

---

### Solution

Effectively, your code block will be:

```
def click():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe", options=options_)
    driver.get("http://www.discord.com")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  

def click():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe", 
    chrome_options=options_)
    driver.get("http://www.discord.com")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'your xpath')
```

This works for By.CLASS_NAME, By.CSS_SELECTOR and etc