# Selenium: get() not working with custom google profile

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options, chrome-profile

All what im trying to do is pretty much access whatsapp web where I have my whatsapp already linked, However when I use a custom profile the profile does open, however `browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com)` doesn't seem to open. or any browser.get(). What could be the issue?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, WebDriverException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/omarassouma/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/')
options.add_experimental_option("deatch", True)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

this is the updated version, it now opens whatsapp web however not in a custom profile, moreover I cant really use webdriver.options(), is there anything extra I have to import?.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/omarassouma/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/omarassouma/Downloads/chromedriver",options=options)
browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- To use a [*Custome Chrome Profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280195/7429447) you have to pass the absolute path as follows:

  ```
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/omarassouma/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399027/7429447)

- Instead of passing the absolute path of the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) binary, you need to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) through the ***key*** *`executable_path`*.
- Additionally, instead of `chrome_options` you need to use *`options`* as [`chrome_options` is deprecated now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63310208/7429447).

> You can find a detailed discussion in [DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options error using Brave Browser With Python Selenium and Chromedriver on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030107/7429447)

So effectively the line of code will be:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver", options=options)
```

Comment: I edited my code according to what you said, but: 1) I did changes according to what you told me, however its not opening google in custom profile anymore but instead whatsapp web is opening 2) I don know how to use .options instead of chromeOptions it doesn't really let me use such option.

Comment: You still need to change `chrome_options=options` as **`options=options`**

Comment: Your right, i still did that and still its not working ( not opening custom google profile , but opening WhatsApp web works fine )

Comment: @OmarAssouma How would you confirm _ not opening custom google profile_?

Comment: its opening google chrome using a guest and not a specific profile. Thus each time my code opens whatsapp web ill have to scan the barcode which is not really what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

At 05.11.2022 I found the only way to pass through authorization for myself is using cookie - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521
Runing selenium driver with google account isn't working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).